# How can I group list items as child lists with jQuery or CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, list, html-lists

I have an unordered list with ten list items and I want to wrap the last 4 items with a child list.
My html is:

```
<ul>
<li class="my1item">my1item</li>
<li class="my2item">my2item</li>
<li class="my3item">my3item</li>
<li class="my4item">my4item</li>
<li class="my5item">my5item</li>
<li class="my6item">my6item</li>
<li class="my7item">my7item</li>
<li class="my8item">my8item</li>
<li class="my9item">my9item</li>
<li class="my10item">my10item</li>
</ul>
```

So I want to add with jQuery OR do some magic with css and have this:

```
 <ul>
<li class="my1item">my1item</li>
<li class="my2item">my2item</li>
<li class="my3item">my3item</li>
<li class="my4item">my4item</li>
<li class="my5item">my5item</li>
<li class="my6item">my6item</li>
 <ul class="wrap">
    <li class="my7item">my7item</li>
    <li class="my8item">my8item</li>
    <li class="my9item">my9item</li>
    <li class="my10item">my10item</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: Why is invalid? it is a ul inside another ul, please check the result code completed

Comment: It's invalid because a `<ul>` can't be a child of another `<ul>`. You would need to make the inner list a child of a list item.

Comment: @geoplous _“Why is it invalid?”_ — just [validate it](https://html5.validator.nu/). You can’t have `<ul>` as a child of a `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using jQuery's `wrapAll` function - and by specifying which elements you don't want to be included.

```js
$('.list').children('li').not(':nth-child(-n+6)').wrapAll('<ul class="wrap" />');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="my1item">my1item</li>
  <li class="my2item">my2item</li>
  <li class="my3item">my3item</li>
  <li class="my4item">my4item</li>
  <li class="my5item">my5item</li>
  <li class="my6item">my6item</li>
  <li class="my7item">my7item</li>
  <li class="my8item">my8item</li>
  <li class="my9item">my9item</li>
  <li class="my10item">my10item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It make your code runnable and it doesn't seem to do what the OP is after. It's also best to let them show what they've tried first.

Comment: You could simplify to `$('.list > li')`, but I agree with j0.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt